# Why SSH shows this message repeatedly?

Tags: linux, ssh

Hi I was connecting to my PC from my home using SSH protocol for the past couple of weeks. Today when I wanted to connect to my PC it showed this message:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the DSA key sent by the remote host is
e4:e2:ac:f0:d1:1b:72:56:f0:47:4a:68:95:54:e1:a3.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/dimit/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /home/dimit/.ssh/known_hosts:1
  remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/home/dimit/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 10.136.18.76
DSA host key for 10.136.18.76 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

By searching the Internet, I realized this is a common problem for SSH so I tried to solve it according to the proposed solutions such as:

```
ssh-keygen -R hostname

or

rm .ssh/known_hosts 

....
```

so after doing these solutions the messages disappeared. but when I'm asked to enter the password and I do, it tells me the password is wrong !!. I tried all the solutions but none of them worked for me. I ran SSH with -v option and here is the output:

```
dimit@dimit-GE620-GE620DX-FX620DX:~$ ssh -v ivan@10.136.18.76
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.136.18.76 [10.136.18.76] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/dimit/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/dimit/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/dimit/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/dimit/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/dimit/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/dimit/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version dropbear_0.51
debug1: no match: dropbear_0.51
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: DSA e4:e2:ac:f0:d1:1b:72:56:f0:47:4a:68:95:54:e1:a3
debug1: Host '10.136.18.76' is known and matches the DSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/dimit/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_dss_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dimit/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dimit/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/dimit/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
ivan@10.136.18.76's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
ivan@10.136.18.76's password: 
Mdebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
Permission denied, please try again.
ivan@10.136.18.76's password: 
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
dimit@dimit-GE620-GE620DX-FX620DX:~$
```

I thought someone must have changed the password !!! so I went to my office today and when I connected my laptop to my pc it also showed the first message but the only difference was that all the above solutions worked for me and in there I was able to connect to my PC with the old password !!!

I thought the problem is solved but When I came home the first message still appears when I remove the known_hosts file it tells me the password is wrong and I'm sure it is not !!!!

So it seems that I can connect to my PC in my office but not in my home !!!
I'm sure There were  no network modification both for the office and my home. And still I don't know what to do ! I didn't have this problem for the past couple of weeks !

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that the IP address you are connecting to from home is (now) wrong.

You ran the ssh command and it told you the problem: You are connecting to a different machine. You ignored that advise and deleted ssh's knowledge of the machine, then connected and told a different machine your password.

Then you connected at work, which (probably) went to the correct machine (but ssh thought it was wrong), you made ssh forget again and it worked.

You should:

1. Fix the IP address you are connecting to (maybe DHCP changed externally?).
2. Change your password, since you've given it to some unknown server.

Comment: Thanks man, Do you mean that "ssh ivan@10.136.18.76" goes to another machine ?!! I think it's impossible !!! if so, why the PC doesn't complain about duplicate IP address ? and why it ask me the password for the user if its on another computer ?! the user "ivan" only reside in my PC and not anywhere else

Comment: I don't know enough details of your network to answer the first question, but DHCP can reassign addresses periodically. To the second question: SSH doesn't validate the username before asking for the password - otherwise it would be easy to find out the valid users on a machine just by trying ssh with different usernames.

Comment: 10.* is a private IP range, so I'm not sure how your network is setup to allow you to get to your work machine from your home network.

Comment: the IP address is a static IP and is not assigned by a DHCP server . This is why I'm sure there's only one machine in my office with this IP address. Tomorrow I will change the password to check if the problem is sovled or not !!!